# Converting a list of integers into a single value

Tags: python

If I had list of integers say,

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Is there an in-built function that can convert this into a single number like 12345? If not, what's the easiest way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int("".join(str(X) for X in x))
```

You have not told us what the result for `x = [1, 23, 4]` should be by the way...
My answer gives 1234, others give 334

Comment: Or simpler: `int(''.join(map(str, x)))`

Comment: I receive a value from a function in list format. So I have to concatenate them to get the full value. Example, I get a value [3,2,0,0] which is actually 3200, so i need to join the elements to get a single value and then manipulate it.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> listvar = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> reduce(lambda x,y:x*10+y, listvar, 0)
12345
```

Comment: @wim, To [quote the BDFL](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196), "So now reduce(). This is actually the one I've always hated most, because, apart from a few examples involving + or *, almost every time I see a reduce() call with a non-trivial function argument, I need to grab pen and paper to diagram what's actually being fed into that function before I understand what the reduce() is supposed to do. So in my mind, the applicability of reduce() is pretty much limited to associative operators, and in all other cases it's better to write out the accumulation loop explicitly."

Comment: Just say no to `reduce`, kids.

Answer (score 4):

If they're digits like this,

```
sum(digit * 10 ** place for place, digit in enumerate(reversed(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun :)

```
int(str(x)[1:-1].replace(', ', ''))
```

Surprisingly, this is even faster for large list:

```
$ python -m timeit -s "x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]*100" "int(str(x)[1:-1].replace(', ', ''))"
10000 loops, best of 3: 128 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s "x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]*100" "int(''.join(map(str, x)))"
10000 loops, best of 3: 183 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s "x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]*100" "reduce(lambda x,y:x*10+y, x, 0)"
1000 loops, best of 3: 649 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s "x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]*100" "sum(digit * 10 ** place for place, digit in enumerate(reversed(x)))"
100 loops, best of 3: 7.19 msec per loop
```

But for very small list (maybe more common?) , this one is slowest.

Comment: I don't see why you determine what is the right and wrong thing to do in the face of list items greater than nine. OP doesn't seem to mention anything.

Comment: (Nor do I see why timing this is appropriate and constructive. We certainly don't determine what code to use primarily on the basic of microbenchmarks.)

Comment: @Mike You are right, I've changed my code. The timing is just for large list situation, as mentioned above.

Comment: actually the maximum length for the list i need is 9

Comment: @user680730 In that case, this is slowest. As what I said, just for fun :)